# How to create a dataframe with various length of rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having a list of list `paths` which shown below ?

The Code is :

```
   for (each in paths)
   {
     print (each)
   }
```

The output is :

```
[1] "1" "2"
[1] "1" "2" "3"
[1] "1" "2" "3" "5"
[1] "1" "2" "4"
[1] "1" "2" "4" "5"
[1] "1" "3"
[1] "1" "3" "5"
[1] "1" "4"
[1] "1" "4" "5"
[1] "1" "5"
[1] "2" "3"
[1] "2" "3" "5"
[1] "2" "4"
[1] "2" "4" "5"
[1] "3" "5"
[1] "4" "5"
```

How to append this all as a rows of a data frame. `as.data.frame` fails due to unequal rows length.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, a `data.frame` needs to have equal row lengths. You could either keep it as a list or pad the rows with `NA` so they're all the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data frame is rectangular by definition, with the same number of columns in each row. You could set the length of each of your rows to be the same (they will be filled in with `NA`), and then `rbind` them together:

```
maxlength = max(lengths(paths))
paths2 = lapply(paths, function(x) {length(x) = maxlength; return(x)})
paths_df = do.call(rbind, args = paths2)
```

That will give a matrix, but you can easily convert to data frame from there.

Answer (score 0):

`data.frame` needs to be rectangular. Also all elements of a given column need to be the same type of object. Thus, you could have a `data.frame` column composed of object of type `list` which can vary in size.

```
paths=list(1,c(1,2))
df=data.frame("pathNumber"= 1:length(paths))
df$path=paths
```

The result looks like this

```
  pathNumber path
1          1    1
2          2 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have the list as a column of a data frame. This may be desirable if you want to have some other columns.

`df <- data.frame(paths = I(paths))`